# How to render string as html in ZF2 Radio form element? escape false

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In `ZF1` i could render a string as `html` like this:

```
$firstPhoto = new Zend_form_Element_Radio('firstPhoto', array('escape' => false));
```

I then could populate my `radio elements` and all is well.

In `ZF2` i can not find a sollution to this problem. I set my valueOptions with an array with an `key(id)` and `value(image string)` and i want to render the img string as an image and not as html.

Anyone knows what to do?